# MailItem Sent Invalid Use

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

**Background**:

 The [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405423/outlook-send-event-class/38407819#38407819) provides a further explanation. 
In this case, I want to know why if I set the email as object I get an error of "invalid use of property" in the [MailItem.Sent Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868242.aspx).

**Problem**

By adding outlook reference to the project:

Code with error invalid use of property(.Sent):

***SetEmailAsObjectCode***

```
Dim olApp As Object: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim EmailToSend As Object
Set EmailToSend = Nothing
    Set EmailToSend = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    With EmailToSend
    On Error Resume Next
    Call .Sent
    If Err.Number = 0 Then ' 4. If Err.Number = 0
    Cells(1,1).Value = "ErrorOutLookTimeout: Email not sent"
    Else ' 4. If Err.Number = 0
    Cells(1,1).Value = "Email Sent!"
    End If ' 4. If Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo 0
    End With
```

Working code:

***SetCreateItemObjectCode***

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim EmailToSend As Outlook.MailItem
    Set EmailToSend = Nothing
        Set EmailToSend = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        With olApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        Call .Sent
        If Err.Number = 0 Then ' 4. If Err.Number = 0
        Cells(1, 1).Value = "ErrorOutLookTimeout: Email not sent"
        Else ' 4. If Err.Number = 0
        Cells(1, 1).Value = "Email Sent!"
        End If ' 4. If Err.Number = 0
        On Error GoTo 0
        End With
```

As you may notice, instead of referencing to the email object created it's set right away

**Question:**

Why does the code ***SetCreateItemObjectCode*** works and the ***SetEmailAsObjectCode*** is not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CreateItem` return an Object. Where as `Outlook.MailItem` is a class itself and when you do `Set EmailToSend = olApp.CreateItem(0)` although the `EmailToSend` variable accommodates the returned `Object` , it no more expose the `.Sent` property. hence the error.

use this :

```
With EmailToSend
On Error Resume Next
Call .ItemProperties.Item("Sent")
```

Comment: I see, I kind of figure it had to do with the missing part of OOP logic that I'm yet to fully understand, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to send a message, you need to call the `MailItem.Send` method. If you are trying to find out if a message is a draft or a sent one, you read the `MailItem.Sent` property.

Note "d" vs "t".

Comment: I'm checking if the message was sent or not; this is achieved by  _**SetCreateItemObjectCode**_, but, I get an error "invalid use of property" with _**SetEmailAsObjectCode**_, I want to know why since both of them would likely be using the same object in the With Statement

Comment: the right syntax would be "if EmailToSend.Sent then...". In your case however, the message is just created using CreateItem, of course it will be unsent.

Comment: Since the With is since the beginning I don't see the logic why to add it again, could you care to explain why? `With EmailToSend` .... `EmailToSend.Sent` ... `End With`?

Comment: You are missing the point - "call" is used when you invoke a method or a sub. For a Boolean property, it must be a part of an expression, such as "if..then". You can use "if EmailToSend.Sent then...", or "if  .Sent then..."., it makes zero difference. Once again, the Sent property check does nto make any sense here - the message is unsent. until it is moved to the Sent Items folder. But it will be a different item with a different entry id by then.

Comment: I tried as suggested prior to posting `if EmailToSend.Sent then`... , it always returned false.

Comment: Of course it always returns false - see my previous reply.