# Pass a variable between Outlook and Excel - was email actually sent

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Not even sure if this is possible but wanted to ask anyway.
I have an Excel sub where I create an Outlook e-mail which is then displayed for editing on a user's PC.
I know how to do all of the coding to mark Excel to show that the e-mail was created but what I don't know is whether the user actually pressed the "Send" button or not.
Is there any way to pass a TRUE variable back to Excel if the user does indeed press the "Send" button or leave it as False if they do not?

Comment: [I asked this about 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405423/outlook-send-event-class), and then [inquired a little bit more in that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442315/mailitem-sent-invalid-use) time does fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the [Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.send(even)) event of the Outlook item displayed, or consider using the `ItemSend` event of the `Application` class to handle all outgoing items in Outlook.

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 
Sub SendMyMail() 
 Set myItem = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 myItem.To = "Eugene"
 myItem.Subject = "Data files information" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub myItem_Send(Cancel As Boolean) 
 myItem.ExpiryTime = #2/2/2023 4:00:00 PM# 
End Sub
```

Comment: As for my original question "is this possible", you answered it, Eugene. While I haven't tried it yet, between the code that you posted along with the link from Sgdva, I'm sure that I can get it to work. Will post back after I get a chance to try it out.